# List all unicode codes between U+E000–U+F8FF using Python

Tags: python, unicode

How would you list all PUA unicode character codes in a list in python?
I was playing around with `chr()` and `defaultdict(list)`. I couldn't figure how to list them all.

Comment: And what are PUA unicode codes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas
I am trying to get a list of those and loop through them.

Comment: That's a fixed range of codepoints; are you having trouble generating those ranges?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly.

Comment: TBH I don't really understand what the U+E000 syntax means.

Comment: It's a hexadecimal number. `U+hhhh` is the hexadecimal number of a unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a range; the codepoints for the [Private Use Areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) of the BMP are all codepoints between (hex) E000 and F8FF:

```
pua = [chr(i) for i in range(0xE000, 0xf900)]
```

for Python 3.

Python 2 version, using the [`unichr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr):

```
pua = [unichr(i) for i in xrange(0xE000, 0xf900)]
```

Comment: `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: @Johnston: Python 2 vs Python 3. I gave you both options now.

Comment: you could also use `map()`: pua = map(unichr, xrange(0xe000, 0xf8ff + 1))`