# python or numpy list involves all unicode characters

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

Can I find any ready python or numpy list which involves all unicode characters?

Or, is there any ready function in python to extract them out from a list?

Comment: If you want to filter every valid unicode character out of your string, it is likely that there will be nothing left…

Comment: No, I need the exact list of it. I will create a probability table.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229797/list-all-unicode-codes-between-ue000-uf8ff-using-python), and change the range to match everything.